# Android ContentValues: Are values misordered at insert?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Obviously I didn't understand the concept of ContentValues in Android. How is it guaranteed that an insert statement like **database.insert(TABLE, null, contentValues);** obtains all values of contentValues in the right order, since ContentValues is a set?

Let's say TABLE has 3 string columns. If I write the following...

```
contentValues.put("col1", valueCol1);
contentValues.put("col2", valueCol2);
contentValues.put("col3", valueCol3);
```

...it is not guaranteed that database.insert inserts the values in this order, or did I understand something wrong?

What are the benefits in using database.insert instead of db.execSQL at all (except better View handling in Android)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> since ContentValues is a set?

`ContentValues` much more closely resembles a `Map`. It is key-value store, keyed by strings.

> it is not guaranteed that database.insert inserts the values in this order, or did I understand something wrong?

An `INSERT` will insert those values simultaneously, the way `INSERT` statements have worked for the past couple of decades in any SQL-compliant database.

To use your example, if we were to `insert()` that `ContentValues` into a table named `foo`, the result would be equivalent to the following:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO foo (col3, col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", args);
```

where `args` is a `String[]` consisting of `valueCol3`, `valueCol1`, and `valueCol2`, respectively.

> What are the benefits in using database.insert instead of db.execSQL at all

It involves a bit less typing, and you do not have to convert your values to a `String` array.

> (except better View handling in Android)?

IMHO, `insert()` on `SQLiteDatabase` does not offer "better View handling" than does `execSQL()` on `SQLiteDatabase`, though perhaps you are thinking of something that I am missing.

Comment: Ok sorry, was a stupid question. After a little break it was clear to me. The keys of the Map itself are the columns, so the framework knows where to insert the values.

Comment: @Bevor: Correct. This does limit you to simple CRUD-style `INSERT` statements, though. If you wanted to do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM ...` statement, that you would have to do via `execSQL()`. And, of course, you are welcome to do all your inserts via `execSQL()` if you prefer.